# Call a javascript function after a form is loaded in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm loading a dropdown value on the change of a dropdown on Add Form. But on edit if both the values are selected both must be populated.
Now I'm thinking to do like this:-

I have made a javascript function which will take the selected value of the first dropdown and do an ajax call and fetch the data for second dropdown.

Now the problem is when and how  should I call the function?

One way is call the function after the form loads.And this where I need your help.How to call the function after the form is loaded?

Here's The function:

```
function getTypeOfLocation(munId){
        $('#cad_type_of_location_id > option').remove();
        $.getJSON("/cad/get_typeoflocation?" + 'id=' + munId, function(data) {

            if (data.length != 0) {
                var opt = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option with for each city
                opt.val(data[0].id);
                opt.text(data[0].name);
                $('#cad_type_of_location_id').append(opt); //here we will append these new select options to a dropdown with the id 'cities'

             } else {
                   var opt = $('<option value=""> No Data </option>');
                   $('#cad_type_of_location_id').append(opt);
             }
        });
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to call the function when you change the value of the first dropdown. `$('#cad_type_of_location_id').change(function(){ // Call your function here });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on()` to delegate a `change` handler so the `select` doesn't need to exist when you run the code. Basically what this means is you can create the delegated change handler in your page load code, before the form exists.

```
$(document).on( 'change', '#ID_of_select', function(){
   getTypeOfLocation( $(this).val() );
})
```